# Ruby Backup gem failing when uploading to S3. connection reset after 37 min

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, backup, fog, excon

The backups are 250MB. I don't think that's very big, but it appears the problem is increasing with the size.

Log from the Backup gem below.

Note the time span; about 37 min into the uploading I get connection reset.

```
[2015/10/30 09:20:40][message] Storage::S3 started transferring '2015.10.30.09.20.01.myapp_postgres.tar' to bucket 'myapp-backups'.
[2015/10/30 09:57:06][error]   ModelError: Backup for Back up PostgreSQL (myapp_postgres) Failed!
[2015/10/30 09:57:06][error]   An Error occured which has caused this Backup to abort before completion.
[2015/10/30 09:57:06][error]   Reason: Excon::Errors::SocketError
[2015/10/30 09:57:06][error]   Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Does this happen after 37 min each time?

Comment: no, it varies. it doesn't even happen all the time, but sporadically more often

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the error handing options, which retransmit the file's portions that have failed :

```
store_with S3 do |s3|
  s3.max_retries = 10
  s3.retry_waitsec = 30
end
```

Keep also the chunk size small:

```
store_with S3 do |s3|
  s3.chunk_size = 5 # MiB
end
```

You may also want to use the [Splitter options](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/splitter/).

Comment: I've got tests out now with the retry options. I had also set chunk size 4000, think it was a count, not a size metric.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `max_retries=' for #<Backup::Storage::S3:0x007f9c7c6f58e0>

Comment: Which backup gem version do you have?

Comment: I need to work more on it, updating etc and I'm too busy right now (what a cliche). Giving you the bounty Renaud, but won't accept any answer until proven, so I don't mislead anybody. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Renaud, I had to fight alot with chef, throwing knifes and cookbooks around. I'm not a master-chef to be honest :D Finally I got backup gem upgraded. Preliminary results are very positive, I'll keep monitoring and update here for other readers' interests too.

Comment: Thanks oma for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I wuold say for now to use ruby-xz to compress in a smaller file in order to send it more compressed and temprary patch it, then try to see

`Excon.defaults[:write_timeout] = 500`

or more 
would do the trick